# kernel compilation: how to exclude module

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, kernel-modules, modprobe, module

I used to compile patched kernel for my Arch Linux machine.  Up until now, I compiled my kernel with ALL modules, or better, I have not customized it.  The reason why is due to my inexperience of this part of Linux world.

In the meantime, I got to know the smart [modprobed-db tool](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Modprobed-db), which is great but it does not fit my needs and mindset: I think former tool is perfect for "limited" machines that never need any other modules. My case is different because I use a laptop, thus I often connect it with "foreign" devices that I have never used before, thus this approach does not work with me. Indeed, I can easily identify modules that will never be used on a laptop (i.e., modules related to server, fibre channel).

So long story short, the question is: How can I exclude modules (or a class or them) from the kernel compilation?

Comment: I take it you mean without going through `make menuconfig` or similar and disabling the modules you don’t want, is that right?

Comment: Yes. It looks like to use ’menuconfig’ you need an advanced knowledge, and mostly I need a "portable" way between kernel compilations